# SQL order by query for string by converting or Boxing or spliting it to integer

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to use Order by query for ChildID column, but ChildID column data type is string is it possible to use Boxing, split function or to Convert, I'm using C# and sql server r2 2008.

```
ChildID
    19/2014-2015,
    20/2014-2015,
    02/2014-2015,
    01/2014-2015,
```

Comment: What is the desired sort order?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to convert it to and in what order you want it to appear. If you want to split it, you can use `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

Comment: Do you mean convert the characters that precede the slash in it or convert the entire thing to an int by removing the non-numeric characters?

Comment: Yes,i want to display in this order                              01/2014-2015                                                  02/2014-2015                                                       19/2014-2015                                              20/2014-2015

Comment: @shashisampige: Which bit determines the order? is it 01, 02,19,20 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your ORDER BY clause, it should get you started. I suspect you'll need to modify it if you have anything other than `2014-2015` after the slash

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(ChildID, 1, CHARINDEX('/', ChildID))
```